# Converting Minutes to 24 hours format

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Problem description:

If I enter :

journey time : 15 minutes

first_train_time:1300   --->half past nine

last_train_time : 1500  ---> three o clock

frequency_time : 15 minutes

To get the right output, first column starts with specific time 1300 and increased by (frequency_time) until the specified (last_train_time).

Second column starts with (first_train_time+frequency_time+2 minutes).

Third column starts with (first_train_time+2*frequency_time+2*2 minutes).

Fourth column starts with (first_train_time+3*frequency_time+3*2 minutes).

Fifth column starts with (first_train_time+4*frequency_time+3*2 minutes).

The output should be:

```
col 1     col2    col3   col4    col5
1300      1317    1334   1351    1406
1315      1332    1349   1406    1421
1330      1347    1404   1421    1436
1345      1402    1419   1436    1451
1400      1417    1434   1451    1506
1415      1432    1449   1506    1521
1430      1447    1504   1521    1536
1445      1502    1519   1536    1551 
1500      1517    1534   1551    1606
```

When i run the following function, i got some weird results (why 
    doesn't print out 1445 and so on ).

```
cout<<"Enter the journey time (minutes) \n"
cin>>journey_time;
cout<<"Enter the first train time \n";
cin>>first_train_time;
cout<<"Enter the last train time \n";
cin>>last_train_time;
cout<<"Enter the frequency time \n";
cin>>frequency_time;
auto get_24hr = [](int minutes){ return (minutes/60)*100 + (minutes%60);};
auto get_minutes = [](int time_24){return (time_24/100)*60+  (time_24 % 100);};

for (int total_min_start= first_train_time; total_min_start <=last_train_time; total_min_start +=frequency_time)
{`
auto x = get_minutes(total_min_start); 
cout<<get_24hr(x)<<" \t "<<get_24hr(x+journey_time+waiting)<<" \t "<<get_24hr(x (2*journey_time+2*waiting)) <<" \t "<<get_24hr(x+(3*journey_time+3*waiting))<<" \t "<<get_24hr(x+(4*journey_time+3*waiting))
}}

 Wrong output :

 1300 1317 1334 1351 1406

 1315 1332 1349 1406 1421

 1330 1347 1404 1421 1436

 1345 1402 1419 1436 1451

 1400 1417 1434 1451 1506

 1415 1432 1449 1506 1521

 1430 1447 1504 1521 1536

 1405 1422 1439 1456 1511 -------> here the problem: it must be 1445, 1504 and so on 

 1420 1437 1454 1511 1526

 1435 1452 1509 1526 1541

 1450 1507 1524 1541 1556

 1505 1522 1539 1556 1611

 1520 1537 1554 1611 1626

 1535 1552 1609 1626 1641
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: So, how should we recreate your output?  Especially the case that you are getting a Wrong Answer for.

Comment: Why do you think it should output 1445 and so on? You convert minutes to hours*100+minutes format and then do arithmetic on *that*. Of course that's going to have weird stuff because when the minutes part overflows, it turns 100 minutes into one hour.

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please see my following example @ThomasMatthews

Comment: Please see my following example @eusoubrasileiro

Comment: Please see my following example @Norrius

Comment: I *think* you don't need `x = get_minutes(total_min_start)` (use `total_min_start` as `x`), but I might be wrong.